# It doesn't find my class even if it exists

Tags: codeigniter-3, ion-auth

This is the error:

Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci-blog-master\application\modules\admin\controllers\Settings.php on line 4
   A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'Admin_Controller' not found

Filename: controllers/Settings.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:

And here is my code for :

Admin_controller.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {

function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
}
}
```

And here is my Settings.php

```
class Settings extends Admin_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->allow_group_access(array('admin'));

        $this->load->model('Category');
        $this->data['parent_menu'] = 'post';
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message',message_box('Setting is the coming soon feature!','danger'));
        redirect('admin/posts/index');

        $config['base_url'] = site_url('admin/categories/index/');
        $config['total_rows'] = count($this->Category->find());
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4;

        $this->data['categories'] = $this->Category->find($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));

        $this->data['pagination'] = $this->bootstrap_pagination($config);
        $this->render('admin/categories/index');
    }

    public function add(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'required|is_unique[categories.name]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'status', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
            $category = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status')
            );
            $this->Category->create($category);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message',message_box('Category has been saved','success'));
            redirect('admin/categories/index');
        }

        $this->render('admin/categories/add');
    }

    public function edit($id = null){
        if($id == null){
            $id = $this->input->post('id');
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'status', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
            $category = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'status' => $this->input->post('status')
            );
            $this->Category->update($category, $id);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message',message_box('Category has been saved','success'));
            redirect('admin/categories/index');
        }

        $this->data['category'] = $this->Category->find_by_id($id);

        $this->render('admin/categories/edit');
    }

    public function delete($id = null){
        if(!empty($id)){
            $this->Category->delete($id);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message',message_box('Category has been deleted','success'));
            redirect('admin/categories/index');
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message',message_box('Invalid id','danger'));
            redirect('admin/categories/index');
        }
    }

    public function update_multiple(){
        #test commit
        #test commit di branch sendiri
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought, but did you try: class Admin_controller extends MY_Controller

Answer (score 1):

You can put more classes in `MY_Controller.php` file:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function some_mycontr_method()
    {
        // appropriate code here
    }
}

class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function some_admin_method()
    {
        // appropriate code here
    }
}
```